# Display no values when array empty Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular.js and trying to determine what the easiest way would be for me would be to display message 'no values found' when array is empty.

I have tried this which is not working

```
 <ul>
        <li ng-show="!items.length">No values</li>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString">                
            <p>{{i.title}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And my controller

```
app.filter('searchFor', function () {
return function (arr, searchString) {
    if (!searchString) {
        return arr;
    }
    var result = [];
    searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
    angular.forEach(arr, function (item) {
        if (item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
            result.push(item);
        }
    });
    console.log(result.length);
    return result;
}
});
```

How could I display the message 'No values found' when there are no values returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use filtered array in ng-if or ng-show

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in filteredItems = (items | searchFor:searchString)">                
        <p>{{i.title}}</p>
    </li>
    <li ng-show="!filteredItems.length">No values</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<ul>
     <li ng-show="!(items | searchFor:searchString).length">
           No values
     </li>
     <li ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString">                
            <p>{{i.title}}</p>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Try the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cprkzpux/)